# JavaScript continuously executing and then stops

Tags: javascript, html, onload, onload-event

I created a js file and created a function and what it supposed to do is change the image once everytime my page is loaded..

```
function swapPic() {
    var imgSrc = [];
    imgSrc[0] = "/Content/Resources/cafe1.jpg";
    imgSrc[1] = "/Content/Resources/cafe2.jpg";
    imgSrc[2] = "/Content/Resources/cafe3.jpg";
    imgSrc[3] = "/Content/Resources/cafe4.jpg";
    imgSrc[4] = "/Content/Resources/cafe5.jpg";
    imgSrc[5] = "/Content/Resources/cafe6.jpg";

    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    var img = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
    img.setAttribute("src", imgSrc[randomnumber]);
    // alert("ok");
}
```

In my html code, in my img tag:

```
<img id="imgContainer"  src="~/Content/Resources/cafe3.jpg" onload="swapPic()"/>
```

Adding the `alert("ok")` line and i reload the page once, the alert window keeps popping up and the image changes. I keep closing the window, and it still pop ups and the image changes. It just stopped after some time.

So I guess, during the time i did not include that `alert("ok")` line, my function is continuously called and stop. It just happen so fast which makes it look like fine.

I think this is a problem. Do you have any idea guys how can I make sure that my function is just called once?

Comment: Does it work if you put `onload` on the `<body>` tag instead of on the `<img>` tag?

Comment: it just load once when i put it in the body tag. thanks to you.
but i am doing this in mvc4 asp.net and my body tag is in a shared layout html. the img tag above is in a "view" and i have several other views. my body tag is a generic body tag that generates any of those views. with that, i think its a bad idea to call a function with an onload event in a body tag that is used by many sub-html codes.

Comment: You could just insert another <script> tag in your view, and call the function from there. <script type="text/javascript">swapPic()</script>. It doesn't have to go in body.onload, just keep it out from img.onload

Comment: its ok now, like what they said, just use window.onload....
i cant use a script tag in my view because im trying to bundle my scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

images have their own load event that refers to when the *image* finishes loading. so, each time you update the src, the browser of course starts loading the image, and fires the event again once it finishes loading it. the cycle repeats.

You could use `window.onload` to call your function just once, because the window's load event can only happen once.

Answer (score 4):

You should add `onload`on the `body`, not the `img`.

```
<body onload="swapPic();">
    <img id="imgContainer"  src="~/Content/Resources/cafe3.jpg"/>
</body>
```

If you add `onload` to the `img`, then the function will be called each time the image is loaded, which causes an infinite loop.

If you cannot modify the `body` tag, then replace your current function `swapPic()` with this:

```
(function swapPic() {
    var imgSrc = [];
    imgSrc[0] = "/Content/Resources/cafe1.jpg";
    imgSrc[1] = "/Content/Resources/cafe2.jpg";
    imgSrc[2] = "/Content/Resources/cafe3.jpg";
    imgSrc[3] = "/Content/Resources/cafe4.jpg";
    imgSrc[4] = "/Content/Resources/cafe5.jpg";
    imgSrc[5] = "/Content/Resources/cafe6.jpg";

    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    var img = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
    img.setAttribute("src", imgSrc[randomnumber]);
    // alert("ok");
})();
```

This will execute it exactly once. No need to call it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You've attached `onload` to an image. In this case `swapPic()` will be called on every image load. So, what happens is an endless loop - you call `swapPic()`, it loads a new image which triggers again `swapPic()`. For more information look at [W3Schools: Event - Img Onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp).

You should move the `swapPic()` to body. This will trigger `swapPic()` only when the body is loaded.

Another way is to use javascript:

```
// if you have jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
    swapPic()
});

// ordinary javascript
window.onload = function() {
    swapPic();
}
```

Comment: Please avoid linking to w3schools (although apparently they are improving slowly).

Answer (score 2):

Use the onload function in  tab. BTW according to your code your `imgSrc[5] = "/Content/Resources/cafe6.jpg";` will never be shown as your random function only generates 0-4.
it should be 
`var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);`